# Modal so fecha quando receber mensagem

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

tenho este código abaixo. Qdo o usuário finaliza o formulário ele fecha a modal de class ".esqFecha". e abre a modal do loading. Porem a modal "esqfecha" so fecha qdo conclui o envia da mensagem e a modal do "loading" fecha antes da modal "esqFecha". Como que eu poderia fazer para a modal "loading" fechar depois que a modal "esqFecha" receber a mensagem

```
$("#formEsq").on("submit", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#loadMe").modal({
      backdrop: "static", //remove ability to close modal with click
      keyboard: false, //remove option to close with keyboard
      show: true //Display loader!
   });
   setTimeout(function () {
      $("#loadMe").modal("hide");}, 3500);

   var enderecoesq = jQuery('.enderecoesq').attr("data-enderecoesq");
console.log(enderecoesq);
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: enderecoesq,
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (retorna) {
         if (retorna['erro']) {
            $('#msgEsq').html(retorna['msg']);
            $('#msgCad').html(retorna['msg']);
            $('.esqFecha').modal('hide');
            $('#loginModal').modal('show');
         } else {
            $('#msgEsq').html(retorna['msg']);
         }
      }
});
```

Comment: O que seria "modal receber a mensagem"? Você não deveria utilizar a *callback* `beforeSend` para exibir o *loading*?

Comment: quando conclui o cadastro no banco de dados ele retorna a mensagem de cadastrado  e ai fecha a modal e vai para a login. ou não cadastrou mantem na modal,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você tem que fechar a modal do loading dentro do callback do AJAX, o bloco da função do `success`. Usar setTimeout pra isso não garante que o tempo que a modal se fechará será sincronizado com o tempo da requisição do AJAX.

Remova o setTimeout e coloque o código `$("#loadMe").modal("hide");` dentro do `success`:

```
$("#formEsq").on("submit", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#loadMe").modal({
      backdrop: "static", //remove ability to close modal with click
      keyboard: false, //remove option to close with keyboard
      show: true //Display loader!
   });

   var enderecoesq = jQuery('.enderecoesq').attr("data-enderecoesq");
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: enderecoesq,
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (retorna) {
         $("#loadMe").modal("hide"); // FECHA O LOADING
         if (retorna['erro']) {
            $('#msgEsq').html(retorna['msg']);
            $('#msgCad').html(retorna['msg']);
            $('.esqFecha').modal('hide');
            $('#loginModal').modal('show');
         } else {
            $('#msgEsq').html(retorna['msg']);
         }
      }
});
```